# paper background image does not appear in exported png/svg/jpeg file

Tags: jointjs

```
paper.toPNG(function (dataURI) {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = dataURI;
      link.setAttribute("download", 'fileName.png');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    });
```

The above code is use to export in PNG format, but the paper background image is not applied to the downloaded image

The background image is applied as flows

```
paper.drawBackground({
        image: 'image url',
        position: 'center',
        repeat: 'no-repeat',
        size: 'cover',
        opacity: 1
      });
```

Comment: It is still not implemented please read more detail here: https://github.com/clientIO/joint/issues/1502#issuecomment-1500091434. But I got on the hack you can take the background Image as one element and set it as interactive false then the element is not able to move so when you try export then it will export as element like others